# Has missing information been provided for the time between the Veronica Mars TV series and the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, veronica-mars, veronica-mars-2014

The Veronica Mars TV series ended with unfinished mysteries and unanswered questions.

The Veronica Mars movie takes place 10 years after the end of the TV series. During those 10 years, Veronica attended Stanford for a Psychology degree, then went to Columbia for a Law degree, and is currently a lawyer in New York.  During her interview at Truman, she reveals she did not work a case after she moved to Stanford.

Did Rob Thomas or any other show creator reveal any additional information for the missing 10 years during interviews?  An extended conversation would be welcome or even a link to a video.

Specific questions:

- Did Veronica get an internship at the FBI?  What happened to that, and why didn't she join the FBI?
- Did Veronica find out who filmed the sex tape, and why?
- What happened during the Sheriff elections? Who won?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary Answer:**

*Why didn't she join the FBI?*
It would be hard to create a movie with all the former cast if she was in a totally different environment.

*Who filmed the sex tape?*
This appears to have been resolved in the TV series.

*What happened in the Sheriff elections?*
Keith Mars lost.

**Detailed Answer**:

I can try and answer some of these questions.

**Why didn't she join the FBI?**

[From an interview pane](http://www.tv.com/shows/veronica-mars/community/post/veronica-mars-paleyfest-139477799737/)l involving the show's creator, Rob Thomas:

> **On the film's original plot:**
>
> The cast is very cognizant of the fact that the film would not have
> been made without the money donated by the fans, and Thomas said that
> once he knew it'd be financed that way, his original idea, which
> involved Veronica as an FBI agent, would no longer work. "I sort of
> abandoned that FBI idea and tried to find a plot to get back to all
> the characters we know and love," said Thomas. "Because if the fans
> are going to pay for a movie, I want them to see the characters they
> love."

In other words, if Veronica were a rookie FBI agent, she would obviously be in a different geographical location, well away from all the former characters. To prevent this possibility, the movie takes place primarily over an old high school reunion so many of the characters can be reunited.

From an interesting article on [FlavorWire](http://flavorwire.com/445880/how-does-the-veronica-mars-movie-compare-to-the-season-4-that-never-happened/):

> I could see how [the FBI idea] would have worked as a successful season of
> Veronica Mars, and definitely one that I, and plenty of fans, would
> watch and enjoy. It was a smart move to reset the setting and
> characters, because that would make the show more accessible to new
> viewers — which is exactly what The CW was looking for. The FBI angle
> turns it into more of a crime drama with a whip-smart lead, rather
> than a teen drama with a sassy lead (because, unfortunately, teen
> dramas will always get a bad rep but crime shows will always be
> popular).
>
> In fact, that’s where the Season 4 pitch wins over the movie: Veronica
> as an FBI agent makes more sense than Veronica as a lawyer. And sure,
> the movie addresses the former career option and, yes, Veronica would
> make a hell of a lawyer (remember the “One Angry Veronica” episode?),
> but it’s not her. She needs to be constantly on the move, solving
> cases, and in the mud. Thomas seems to agree; a few months prior to
> starting the Kickstarter, he was still intent on having the film
> center on Veronica in the FBI. Once the show graduated from high
> school, it would naturally become more about the mysteries than the
> setting.
>
> But the Veronica Mars movie was fan service, and that’s why it worked
> so well. The fans are the reason it happened, so Thomas had to abandon
> his original idea because there was no way to do it while bringing
> back all of the favorites from Neptune. The movie was packed with
> callbacks and inside jokes — there is even a clever exchange about
> this pilot pitch, referencing Veronica’s FBI career as something that
> happened in another life — because, essentially, that’s what fans paid
> for. The movie wasn’t much more than a long episode of the show, but
> that’s exactly what I loved about it. Yet I also loved where the show
> was going to go in the season-that-never-happened. It would have been
> great to see a longer version of Veronica adjusting to the FBI and
> generally just kicking ass and shooting bad guys. And maybe we’ll get
> some stories of her in the law enforcement eventually (there are
> rumors of a second movie, and Thomas hasn’t been shy about his desire
> for a Netflix deal) but for now, Veronica’s intriguing alternate life
> will remain too brief.

I think the logic applied here is completely rational. It just wouldn't have worked to have many of the old cast back *and* Veronica in the FBI.

**Who filmed the sex tape?**

The [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/style-blog/wp/2014/03/14/veronica-mars-faq-before-you-see-the-movie-heres-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-show/) did a recap of the series finale before the movie, commenting:

> The series finale seemed more like a season finale. It was
> unsatisfactorily open-ended and left many unresolved issues. Last we
> saw, Veronica she was a freshman studying criminology at Hearst
> College in California. A sex tape of her and boyfriend Stosh “Piz”
> Piznarski (Chris Lowell) mysteriously surfaced. Neptune’s resident bad
> boy and Veronica’s ex-boyfriend Logan Echolls (Jason Dohring) assumed
> Piz was the culprit and beat him to a pulp.
>
> Once it was revealed that
> a secret collegiate society (modeled after Yale’s Skull and Bones) was
> actually behind the tape, Veronica became furious at Logan. She tells
> Logan their friendship is over and wants nothing to do with him, thus
> seemingly choosing the sweet, levelheaded Piz over her former,
> long-time flame (continuing an epic love triangle that picks up in the
> movie).
>
> Vengeful, Veronica hunts down the secret society and stages a
> break-in at a billionaire’s mansion to collect evidence on the
> association’s members. While escaping the residence, she is caught by
> security cameras. Her father, former private eye and current sheriff
> Keith Mars, protects her identity by destroying the surveillance
> footage and, by doing so, jeopardizes his re-election campaign. The
> final scene shows Veronica casting a ballot for her dad in the sheriff
> election and walking off alone, seemingly debating whether her
> sleuthing has caused more harm than good.

I never finished the series myself, but this sounds like that thread was fairly well resolved in the TV series. I'm not aware of any mention of it in the movie.

**Who won the sheriff's election?**

The [Veronica Mars Confessions](http://veronicamarsconfessions.tumblr.com/post/26850387034/i-just-finished-watching-season-3-for-i-just) blog stated:

> Note: Rob Thomas tweeted from his official Twitter (@RobThomas) that
> Keith Mars lost the Sheriff election to Vinny Van Lowe. He also had
> plans for The Castle and Gory Sorokin. As for Logan and Veronica, he
> refused to answer the question. As for the movie, he said “Don’t give
> up.”

Unfortunately I can't find the direct tweet in question, but as I've seen this claim in a few places I assume it is true.

[ScreenRant](http://screenrant.com/veronica-mars-movie-plot-spoilers/) also had an interview with Rob Thomas, where he stated:

> “She transferred away from Hearst college after that freshman year and
> went up to Stanford and finished her undergraduate degree. And then
> she went to Columbia Law School. She’s certainly been back to Neptune
> from time to time to see her dad and Mac and Wallace, but she hasn’t
> worked a PI case since the last one we all saw in the final episode of
> season 3. She ruined her dad’s chance for re-election and she decided
> that that path had caused too much chaos in her life.
>
> “And so she hasn’t worked a PI case in nine years. And when we meet
> her, she’s sort of like where Tom Cruise was in the beginning of The
> Firm. She’s between having graduated and taken the bar and she’s
> interviewing at various law firms in New York.”

**Final Thoughts**

In the same interview as the last quotation, the following exchange occurred:

> **Will the movie be new audience-friendly? According to Thomas:**
>
> “I want to avoid getting deep into the ‘Veronica Mars’ mythology.
> We’re not going to get ghost visits from Lilly, as much as I joked
> about having Amanda Seyfried in it. We’re not going to get into
> Veronica’s backlog of cases. I want to make the movie accessible for
> people who haven’t watched ‘Veronica Mars’ before. All you need to
> know is that Veronica was a teenage private eye and she’s given it up.
> And there will be a moment early in the movie that will bring her back
> to Neptune and make her give being a private detective one more shot.”

Therefore, it does seem like Rob Thomas was trying to target new viewers as well as the old fans. It definitely appears logical then that some of the loose ends were simply left, as it would be too convoluted for new viewers to understand them. Other threads were resolved in the movie and most other discussion points appear to have been addressed in interviews with Rob Thomas and the cast.

Comment: Excellent. Just what i was looking for. Btw, did the why part of sex tape resolved? Not even addressed i feel. Anyway, enjoyed the movie & *hope* for a second one

Comment: @KharoBangdo: I think the _why_ was as simple as wanting to screw with her (by ... er... watching her screw). But there were definitely a lot of loose ends in the show.

Answer (score 1):

*Did Veronica get an internship at the FBI? What happened to that, and why didn't she join the FBI?*

This is addressed in the course of the film as an off-hand comment by one of the characters speaking to Veronica, summarized as, "Someone told me you joined the FBI.", which Veronica dismisses outright as a false rumor.  This was an intentional nod to the proposed FBI season.

Comment: Well, Veronica did get an internship at the FBI during final episodes of season 3. But as it happened she didn't go through with it as seen in the movie